# get all customer payment based on order id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

I wonder if somebody could help me with this complicated mysql query.

I have 3 tables:

Table #1: `Customer_Order` that have two columns `customer_id` and `order_id`
 Table #2: `Order_Payment` that also has `order_id`
 Table #3: `Orders` that has an `id` which is an order id.

I was wandering if it was possible to retrieve all payments from a specific customer based on `order_id`. I only have an `order_id` but I don't have the `customer_id` and based on the `order_id`, I should be able retrieve all the payments and even those that have not been paid yet.

This is how I do it:

I first retrieve the order which is known

```
select * from customer_order where order_id = 1351
```

then I try to build the query based on what is returned

```
select * from (
    select * from customer_order where order_id = 1351
) c1
left join 
    (select op.order_id, customer_id from order_payment op inner join customer_order co on op.order_id = co.order_id
    ) c2 on c1.customer_id = c2.customer_id
```

I also try

```
select customer_id from (
    select customer_id from `order_payment` inner join `customer_order` on `customer_order`.`order_id` = `order_payment`.`order_id` 
    where order_payment.order_id=1351
    order by `created_at` asc) as s
inner join customers on s.customer_id = customers.id
```

but I just get only one order payment and not those that have not been paid.

I would appreciate If someone out there would help me with the solution to the problem.

Comment: How do you want your output to look?

Comment: I'd skip the straight SQL queries, and instead take advantage of Laravel's Eloquent and relationships.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I just cannot think of a way to do this in Laravel. I mean I have orders which has a pivoted tables - customer_order and order_payment but how to connect all of them together to display what was paid and wasn't I can't do. What I can do is to run query twice. First to retrieve everything that have been paid and then run everything which have not been paid. But is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT 
    co.*,
    op.*
FROM
    customer_order AS co
    LEFT JOIN order_payment AS op ON op.order_id = co.order_id

WHERE
    co.customer_id IN 
    (
         SELECT customer_id FROM customer_orders WHERE order_id=1351
    )
```

Comment: I tried the query but only retrieves one order payment. What I needed is to get paid and unpaid orders. If I have 10 orders from  the same customer, and only 1 was paid, I should see 1 paid and 9 unpaid

Comment: So you want orders and not payments. All orders (regardless if they have payment) and if there is payment also payment information? Try modified query.

Answer (score 0):

You can join with `customer_order` twice. Once to go from the given `order_id` to the `customer_id`, then a second time to get all the customer's orders.

```
select op.*
FROM order_payment AS op
JOIN customer_order AS co1 ON co1.order_id = op.order_id
JOIN customer_order AS co2 ON co2.customer_id = co1.customer_id
WHERE co2.order_id = 1351
```

I don't think there's any reason to use `LEFT JOIN`. The columns in `order_payment` should be foreign keys, so there will always be matches.

Comment: I tried the query but only retrieves one order payment. What I needed is to get paid and unpaid orders. If I have 10 orders from  the same customer, and only 1 was paid, I should see 1 paid and 9 unpaid

Comment: The question says **retrieve all payments from a specific customer**. How can there be payments on unpaid orders?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running 2 queries. First load a customer which had completed the payment for a specific order and then load unpaid orders for that customer.

Thanks everyone for your help.